# How do I get the product version for my Silverlight program?

Tags: silverlight-2.0

In Winforms I would use Application.ProductVersion to get the version of my code. Is there an equivalent for Silverlight 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is link that may be helpful to you:
[Determine the version of my Silverlight app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226232/determine-the-version-of-my-silverlight-app)

Answer (score 0):

This can only be done by reflection. The code is

```
using System.Reflection;
Version v = new Version(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName.Split(',')[1].Split('=')[1]);
```

Clunky, but it works.